# How to say "cannot compare/compete with him?"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, words

How do you say these. E.g. I cannot compare/compete with him。　彼と比べらはできない/彼と比べられない/彼と叶わない?
Not sure if 比べ is too literal for comparing to use in this case.

What about "This is no contest."
これで競争できない？これは競争じゃない/がない？相手にはならない？

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple ways to say this.

> 彼にかなわない

「かなう」in this sense is written in kana or as 「敵う」. And the particle should be 「に」, because this is obviously a directional compariso.

Similarly:

> 彼に及ば{およば}ない

In addition:

> 彼と比べものにならない

and

> 彼と比べることはできない

also work.

You can also say 「比較にならない」but "he" would have to be the subject.

> (彼は) 私と比較にならないほど優秀な方だ。

Comment: Thank you! Doesn't 彼と比べることはできない have the confusion where it could also mean that the other party cannot compete/compare with you?

Comment: @shoryuu Sorry, just saw your comment. 「彼と比べることはできない」and「彼と比べものにならない」state you can't compare with them. I don't think there is much space for confusion in these expressions.

Comment: I see! No worries. Better late than never! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to shift the point-of-view to focus on them, you could describe them/their ability with 無双・無敵・無比.

> - 無双の美女　→　Girl/Woman of unequaled beauty
> - 無敵のチーム　→　An unbeatable team
> - 天下無比の歌手　→　An unmatched singer